# How to use use-supercluster with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am having troubles while implementing [use-supercluster](https://github.com/leighhalliday/use-supercluster) with TypeScript. I am trying to use clusters to differentiate two types of data in a Google Map with something like red clusters vs. green clusters.

I can't find any documentation related to use this library with TypeScript and I am not getting enough information from its types:

[image]

So, what is argument `P`? I was following the [`use-supercluster` creator's guide](https://www.leighhalliday.com/google-maps-clustering) to add clusters but after installing `supercluster` types I am getting errors here:

```js
const { clusters } = useSuperCluster({
    points,
    bounds,
    zoom,
    options: { radius: 75, maxZoom: 25 }
});
```

#### Error 1:

[image: errors on points]

I have tried to create manually a `GeoJSONProperty` interface with the following attributes:

```js
interface GeoJSONProperty {
    cluster: boolean;
    pdId: string;
    category: string;
}
```

Then I have tried to assert `points` with `PointFeature<GeoJSONProperty>` but I got a different error:
[image: attempt]

#### Error 2:

[image: errors on bounds]

This one I was able to "solve" it with `const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(undefined);`. But not sure whether that is a good practice.

So, do you know any documentation related to useSuperCluster + TypeScript or just do you know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue, is your code opensource and on Github? It would help me a lot if I could take a look.

Comment: @Bodok, have u tried the answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I found [this file](https://github.com/leighhalliday/use-supercluster/blob/master/example/index.tsx) on the library's repo on Github and it explains pretty straightforward how to use `useSuperCluster()` on TypeScript.

Answering to my own question, it seems that `points` is in fact declared as an array of `PointFeature<GeoJsonProperties>` where `JsonProperties` comes from [geojson library](https://github.com/caseycesari/geojson.js).

Imports:

```js
import { PointFeature } from 'supercluster';
import { BBox, GeoJsonProperties } from 'geojson';
```

Then:

```js
const points: Array<PointFeature<GeoJsonProperties>> = coords.map(pd => ({
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
        cluster: false,
        pdId: pd._id,
        category: 'test'
    },
    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ pd.lat, pd.lng ] }
}));
```

Also, `bounds` seems to be declared as `BBox`, also comes from geojson library. So, to make this work I had to define the bounds in the same state, not after:

```js
const [bounds, setBounds] = useState([
    -52.13013780765266,
    -33.853076010021674,
    -57.12647659234733,
    -32.851013577053855
] as BBox);
```