# use-supercluster gets empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-map-react

After [figuring out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983920/how-to-use-use-supercluster-with-typescript/66000181#66000181) how to deal with TypeScript and [use-supercluster](https://github.com/leighhalliday/use-supercluster) library I have "made it work" until I got a new problem: I get an empty array whenever I use `useSuperCluster()` function.

I am following the [creator's guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NI5e_GTIko&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=LeighHalliday) so I can handle my own project.

This is what I do:

```js
const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(undefined as BBox | undefined);
const { data, error } = useSwr(API_URL, fetcher);
const coords: Array<ParkingData> = data && !error ? data.data : [];
const points: Array<PointFeature<GeoJsonProperties>> = coords.map(pd => ({
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
        cluster: false,
        pdId: pd._id,
        category: 'test'
    },
    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ pd.lat, pd.lng ] }
}));

const { clusters } = useSuperCluster({
    points,
    bounds,
    zoom,
    options: { radius: 75, maxZoom: 25 }
});
```

When I debug `points` I get something like:

[image]

But then, `clusters` is empty. I update `bounds` like in the video with a `onChange` attribute, like:

```js
onChange={({ zoom, bounds }) => {
    setZoom(zoom);
    setBounds([
        bounds.nw.lng,
        bounds.se.lat,
        bounds.se.lng,
        bounds.nw.lat
    ]);
}}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

#### Edit:

I had added `supercluster` object to `useSuperCluster()` destructuring like `const { clusters, supercluster } = useSuperCluster(...)` and after debugging it I get the following object:

[image]

Comment: To those who vote down, it would be great to comment so I can understand what is going on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this line order:

```
geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ pd.lat, pd.lng ] }
```

to:

```
geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ pd.lng, pd.lat ] }
```

apparently, the order is that way, in my case i tried this change and it didn't work for me, but for you there's a chance it will work.

https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/issues/45